# Combinar celdas en DataGridView VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net, visual-studio

La duda que tengo es, como puedo combinar celdas en un DataGridView?

En mi proyecto de VB.NET tengo un DataGridView que muestra información de una tabla de mi base de datos en MySQL de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es combinar las celas de la primera columna para que quede algo como así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo hago?

Las tablas de las imágenes están realizadas en Excel solo para poner el ejemplo, cabe aclarar que solo muestro 2 servicios pero en realidad son 30 servicios.

Comment: siempre cada servicio tendrá tres turnos? o es dinámico ?

Comment: es un DataGridView o GridView el que usas? o sea es un desarrollo web o desktop

Comment: Siempre serán 3 turnos. Es DataGridView, desarrollo desktop!

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea porque marcaste una respuesta si la solucion planteada es para un desarrollo web ?

Comment: Eliminaré mi respuesta, ya que no va al caso.

Comment: Ok! Me podrías ayudar entonces con la solución para el DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la solución perfecta a mi problema, la comparto para que todos la tengan.

En el evento **Load** del **Form** se coloca la siguiente instrucción:

```html
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
End Sub
```

En el evento **CellPainting** del **DataGridView** colocamos lo siguiente:

```html
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
    If (e.RowIndex < 1 Or e.ColumnIndex < 0) Then
        Return
    End If

    If (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)) Then
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
    Else
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridView1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top
    End If
End Sub
```

En el evento **CellFormatting** del **DataGridView** colocamos lo siguiente:

```html
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If (e.RowIndex = 0) Then
        Return
    End If
    If (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex)) Then
        e.Value = ""
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Y adicional necesitamos crear una función:

```html
Private Function IsTheSameCellValue(ByVal column As Integer, ByVal row As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim cell1 As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(column, row)
    Dim cell2 As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1(column, row - 1)
    If (IsDBNull(cell1.Value) Or IsDBNull(cell2.Value)) Then
        Return False
    End If
    If (cell1.Value = cell2.Value) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

El DataGridView no proporciona esta funcionalidad.

En CodeProject si puedes encontrar una implementación de un tipo de columna para DataGridView que permite hacerlo:

[DataGridVewTextBoxCell with Span Behaviour](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour)

Básicamente crea un tipo de columna DataGridViewTextBoxColumnEx cuyas celdas son del tipo DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx. Estas celdas permiten combinar celdas a través de sus propiedades RowSpan y ColSpan.

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Bath/Shower", "Turn 1")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Bath/Shower", "Turn 2")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Bath/Shower", "Turn 3")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Hair Care", "Turn 1")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Hair Care", "Turn 2")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Hair Care", "Turn 3")
    Dim cell As DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx = CType(DataGridView1(0, 0), DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)
    cell.RowSpan = 3
    cell = CType(DataGridView1(0, 3), DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)
    cell.RowSpan = 3
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para usarlo:

1. Descárgate el código del proyecto de la web de CodeProject
2. El código es una solución con 3 proyectos. El que te interesa es SpannedDataGridViewNet2. Añade este proyecto a tu solución
3. En tu proyecto Windows Forms añade una referencia a este proyecto y compila
4. Al añadir columnas en tus DataGridView tendrás la opción de elegir un nuevo tipo de columna: DataGridViewTextBoxColumnEx
5. Las celdas de estas columnas son del tipo DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx que te permiten indicar valores para sus propiedades RowSpan y ColumnSpan como te pongo en el ejemplo

Comment: Se ve genial, es lo que necesito, pero no entiendo muy bien la solución!

Comment: Edito la respuesta para ponerte los pasos de cómo utilizarlo

Answer (score 1):

Podrias optar por una opcion como ser

[How to Merge DataGridView Cell in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms)

en el evento `CellPainting` del DataGridView

alli valida si el valor de la columan es igual al de la celda anterior, si lo es elimina la linea de las celdas usando

```
 e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
```

Tambien hay otra forma mas compleja que utiliza GDI

[MERGING CELLS IN DATAGRIDVIEW](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/merging-cells-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Comment: **Gracias, me sirvió de mucho la primera opción, aunque el código estaba en C# lo pude traducir a VB.NET**